# User Authentication with Mobile No and OTP in MEAN Stack.

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am newbie in mean stack. How to create otp authentication ? I want to register a user when install my app he can register through OTP . Is their any way to do that ? want to user can register through their mobile no. How to create otp login API with MEAN Stack ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the SMS service provider like twilio. To send messages

https://www.twilio.com